# user Profile meta value as custom field

Tags: custom-field

I would like to add custom fields automatically to all my custom post types `weblogs` based on data from the author profile field.

My code:

```
function add_custom_field_automatically($post_ID) {
    global $wpdb;
    $curauth = get_userdata($author->ID);
    if(!wp_is_post_revision($post_ID)) {
        $themevalue = get_the_author_meta('themeperauthor', $author->ID);
        $themename = 'themeperauthor';
        add_post_meta($post_ID, $themename, $themevalue);
    }
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

create a simple query and loop over all posts with your function:

```
//get all your post of that type
my_query = new WP_Query();
my_query->query(array('post_type' => '','posts_per_page' => -1));
if (my_query->have_posts()){
//loop over all post and update meta field with your function
    while (my_query->have_posts()){
        my_query->the_post();
        add_custom_field_automatically_new($post->ID,$post->post_author);
    }
}


//save as your function but with bit of tweaking

function add_custom_field_automatically_new($post_ID,$post_a) {
    if(!wp_is_post_revision($post_ID)) {
        $themevalue = get_the_author_meta('themeperauthor', $post_a);
        $themename = 'themeperauthor';
        add_post_meta($post_ID, $themename, $themevalue);
    }
}
```

after you save this remove it (it only needs to run once).

the use your old function from above and hook it to save_post hook so every time a post is saved it will run

```
add_action('save_post','add_custom_field_automatically');
```

Comment: Thanks Bainternet                                       The problem arise when user changes their profile meta field. It will be great if it can delete and than update by itself

Comment: How can a user change his profile meta?